# I keep getting a really annoying error everytime I run mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven

I keep getting a

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default) on
> project PermissionsPlugin: Error creating shaded jar: Error in ASM
> processing class net/perms/commands/rank/deleteRank.class" error.

I can't figure out what is happening, as Intellij isn't giving me any errors when I build with it. The reason I build with maven is to shade, in case you were wondering. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I found out my issue. My maven shade plugin wasn't up to date... The error has been fixed by Maven a while ago.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, please consider answering your own question so others don't have to waste time searching the comments.

Comment: Maven Shade version 2.1 is really a little bit out of date ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to update the Maven shade plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my issue. My maven shade plugin wasn't up to date... The error has been fixed by Maven a while ago.